# React Native screenProps method not being passed

Tags: react-native

So basically I'm making this small app with a footer that is not based on any navigator or anything, so I'm just including the footer with it's tabs in each screen in order to switch between screens.

There is once stack navigator though, inside a screen, towards which I simply cannot pass a method to alter the state in the main component.

For that purpose, I've made this small snippet here: https://snack.expo.io/BkKbgrKLW

Please tap on `Preview`, or run it with your phone and you'll see the `screenProps` only forwards `foo: "bar"` rather than the `put` method as well.

What am I doing wrong ? Works just fine if I would use a simple `Component` instead of `StackNavigator` .. please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it looks like `put` just APPEARS to not be passed because `JSON.stringify` is hiding it.

You can see in this example that the prop is being passed because you can call the function, which will trigger `setState` and thus another render.

https://snack.expo.io/HJHBwSF8W